# Partial Search In Table(BDE)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I made a database with paradox 7. The usual search I do is a syntax like this:

```
Table.Filter := 'Country=' + QuotedStr(Edit.Text);
```

This returns rows those country field is same as the entered text in edit. when I want to search for countries are beginning by "L" i use this syntax:

```
Table.Filter := 'Country=' + QuotedStr(Edit.Text + '*');
```

But how can I search for fields those are finished with "L"? this syntax does not work:

```
Table.Filter := 'Country=' + QuotedStr('*' + Edit.Text  );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`OnFilterRecord`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TDataSet_OnFilterRecord.html) event to carry out a customized filtering. With your example, maybe sth. like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Table1FilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
var
  s: string;
begin
  Accept := False;
  if not DataSet.FieldByName('Country').IsNull then begin
    s := DataSet.FieldByName('Country').AsString;
    Accept := Copy(s, Length(s), 1) = 'L';
  end;
end;
```