# Delphi 7 : How to search BDE database field for certain keywords

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, bde

I am very new to Delphi and created a simple BDE database with the following fields: Entry number, System, Error, Solution. I want to be able to search the 'Error' field for any keyword(s) and all the entries that contain that keyword should be displayed in another window.

Any help with the coding will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Partial Search In Table(BDE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989982/partial-search-in-tablebde)

Comment: That sounds more like "Filter" than "Search". Have you considered to use the "Filter" and "Filtered" porperties of your TDataSet? Or you have to use the proper SQL with TQuery. Anyway, you have to provide more information. What kind of Database do you use? Is the "keyword" part of the "error"-fiels or is the whole field-value a keyword?

Comment: A thing like BDE database does not exists, maybe you're creating a paradox database trough BDE. I must warn you BDE is deprecated since Delphi 6 or 7 (almost 15 years ago), so if you're learning Delphi start with a supported and current data access layer, like dbExpress.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the TDataSet's Filter property to something like `Error = '*keyword*'`. Assuming that the Keyword is typed in a TEdit control called Edit1, you would use the Edit1Change event to trigger the filtering like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
  Table1.Filter := 'Error = ''' + Edit1.Text + '*''';
  Table1.Filtered := Edit1.Text <> '';
end;
```

The results can be shown in a data-aware grid such as a DBGrid. For the connection between Table1 and the grid you need a TDataSource component: the Grid is linked to the Source, and the Source holds the Table1 in its DataSet property.

A simple way to extend the example to multiple keywords is to use comma-separation:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  stlSep                                : TStringList;
  sFilter                               : string;
  i                                     : Integer;
begin
  stlSep := TStringList.Create;
  stlSep.CommaText := Edit1.Text;
  for i := 0 to stlSep.Count - 1 do
    sFilter := sFilter + ' or Error=''' + stlSep[i] + '*''';
  stlSep.Free;

  Table1.Filter := Copy(sFilter, 4, MaxInt);
  Table1.Filtered := Edit1.Text <> '';
  Table1.Open;
end;
```

Depending on your needs, you might have to replace the `or` by an `and`.